# Show that $P(X \ge r ) = P (Y \le p)$

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

> Let $ X \sim \text{Bin}(n,p) $ and $ Y \sim \text{Beta}(r,n-r+1)  $. Show , without integration by parts, that  $P(X \ge r ) = P (Y \le p)$.

From which point of view I answer this question.

Comment: @Xi'an: The question says show the equality without integration by parts. Then how can I show? I don't understand.

Comment: can you write down any of the two probabilities?

Comment: @Xi'an Yes. $P[X \ge r] = \sum_{x=r}^n {n \choose x} p ^x (1-p)^{n-x}$

Comment: Try to do the same with $$\frac{(n+r)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}\int_0^p y^{r-1}(1-y)^{n-r} \text{d}y$$

Comment: @Xi'an I'm curious where you would go with that integral, given that you are enjoined from integrating by parts. (That injunction probably should be broadly interpreted as an extremely strong hint that no integration at all will be necessary.)  Did you have some particularly simple or elegant manipulation in mind?

Comment: @whuber: yes, I would simply expand the $(1-y)^{n-r}$ using the binomial formula$$(1-y)^{n-r}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-r} (-1)^k {n-r\choose k} y^k$$ and from there the integral is trivial.